# Android Room and LiveData: How to tell ui or parent table to query data again when I updated child table?

Tags: android, kotlin, foreign-keys, android-room

There are two tables, Task and StatisticsTask for Android room, StatisticsTask has foreign key taskId for Task.id. When I update StatisticsTask, how to tell ui query data again?

```
@Entity
@Parcelize
data class Task(
    var name: String,
    var important: Boolean = false,
    var startTime: String = timeHm(),
    var endTime: String = "",
    var remind: String = "",
    var repeat: String = "",
    var repeatInterval: String = "",
    var desc: String = "",
    var endDate: String = "",
    var startDate: String = nowOfString(),
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Int = 0
) : Parcelable {
    @Ignore
    var selected = false
    @Ignore
    var time: String? = null

    @Ignore
    var finished: Boolean = false
}
```

```
@Entity(foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(entity = Task::class, parentColumns = arrayOf("id"), childColumns = arrayOf("taskId"),
    onDelete = CASCADE)])
@Parcelize
data class StatisticsTask(
    var taskId: Int,
    var date: Calendar?,
    var finish: Boolean = false,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int = 0
) : Parcelable {
}
```

```
//TaskViewModel.kt

    fun finishTask(task: Task) {
        launch {
            statisticsTaskDao.updateById(task.id, !task.finished)
        }
    }
```

```
@Dao
interface StatisticsTaskDao {
    @Query("update statisticstask set finish = :finish where taskId=:taskId and date = :date")
    fun updateById(taskId: Int, finish: Boolean, date:Calendar = thisDayInitial())
}
```

```
//in my fragment
val model = ViewModelProviders.of(this)[TaskViewModel::class.java]
model.getAllOfToday().observe(this, Observer<List<Task>> {
    //udpate data to adapter
})
```

```
//I want to finish this task here(in adapter)
iv_finished.setOnClickListener {
       //task: first item in adapter
    model.finishTask(task)

       //This not work. when I finish task, how to update data again?
    model.getAllOfToday()
}
```

This is for android-room 2.2.0-rc1, Android studio 3.5. 
How to tell db query data again? I tried call this again is not working: model.getAllOfToday().observe(this@TodayFragment, Observer> {
                    dispatchData(it)
                })